# Can't get add_image_size to work

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a WordPress theme and am trying to create various different sized images for the images the user uploads into an Advanced Custom Fields image field. However when I use the code below then use the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin to create the new image sizes it doesn't appear to have any affect.

I get the feeling there's something very basic I'm missing as from everything I've read this should work. The code below is a cut down version of the actual function, there's a fair few more image sizes in the one I'm using.

```
function test_add_image_sizes() {
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

  // Images used on blog index & category pages for the first item and at the top of the blog post page itself
  add_image_size( "main-image", 700, 680, true );
  add_image_size( "main-image-350", 350, 450, true ); // For use on screens 350 pixels & below
  add_image_size( "main-image-539", 539, 573, true ); // For use on screens 539 pixels & below
  add_image_size( "main-image-659", 659, 570, true ); // For use on screens 659 pixels & below
  add_image_size( "main-image-850", 850, 650, true ); // For use on screens 850 pixels & below
  add_image_size( "main-image-1000", 1000, 650, true ); // For use on screens 1000 pixels & below
  add_image_size( "main-image-1200", 1200, 680, true ); // For use on screens 1200 pixels & below
  add_image_size( "main-image-1400", 1400, 680, true ); // For use on screens 1200 pixels & above
}
add_action( 'init', 'test_add_image_sizes' );
```

The code above is placed in my themes `functions.php` file.

Comment: Where did you put this code?

Comment: @michaJlS This is in my functions.php file - I'll update my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Hi use `after_theme_setup` hook instead of `init`. User regenerate thumbnail plugin for previously uploaded image size fixing.

```
function test_add_image_sizes() {
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

  // Images used on blog index & category pages for the first item and at the top of the blog post page itself
  add_image_size( "main-image", 700, 680, true );
  add_image_size( "main-image-350", 350, 450, true ); // For use on screens 350 pixels & below
  add_image_size( "main-image-539", 539, 573, true ); // For use on screens 539 pixels & below
  add_image_size( "main-image-659", 659, 570, true ); // For use on screens 659 pixels & below
  add_image_size( "main-image-850", 850, 650, true ); // For use on screens 850 pixels & below
  add_image_size( "main-image-1000", 1000, 650, true ); // For use on screens 1000 pixels & below
  add_image_size( "main-image-1200", 1200, 680, true ); // For use on screens 1200 pixels & below
  add_image_size( "main-image-1400", 1400, 680, true ); // For use on screens 1200 pixels & above
}
add_action( 'after_theme_setup', 'test_add_image_sizes' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have for mine:

```html
// Enable post thumbnails
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

// Custom image sizes
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
 add_image_size( 'carousel-mobile', 640, 400, true );
 add_image_size( 'carousel-tablet', 980, 602, true );
 add_image_size( 'carousel-desk', 1400, 580, true );
 add_image_size( 'feed-thumb', 300, 185, true );
 add_image_size( 'article-featured', 640, 300, true );
 add_image_size( 'list-thumb', 382, 204, true );
}
```

With ACF make sure the image is set to an array and you code it like this

```html
<?php $image = get_field('image'); ?>

<img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['list-thumb']; ?>" alt="">
```

Comment: I've tried something similar to that before - the exception being that I didn't have `add_image_size` wrapped in the if statement but the extra images just don't seem to generate. Instead I get the original image output when I try to access it.

Comment: What happens when you `print_r($image);` does it display the different sizes? Sometimes I've had to resave my image acf field for it to pick up the new sizes.